# How do I stop this program after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit

I just started programming python for GCSE and made a program called do not press the button, it is going good, but at the end there is the part where you need to try to click the enter button(which is impossible on purpose) Does anyone know how to stop it after 10seconds and continue with the program? (I used sources from everywhere the internet, myself and friends, dont get disturbed by the #'s)

```
print("##############################")
print("DO NOT PRESS THE ENTER BUTTON!")
print("##############################")
a = input("")
b = input("Hello?")
name = input("What is your name?\n")
d = input("Aha, you know " + str(name) + " you are very anoying!")

e = input("Stop it!")
f = input("I hate you soooo much")
g = input("I am sure you don't have friends")
h = input("BECAUSE ANOYING PEOPLE DON'T HAVE FRIENDS!!!")
i = input("I just won't answer anymore")
j = input("you will get bored")
k = input(".")
l = input("..")
m = input("...")
n = input("....")
o = input(".....")
p = input("STOOOOOOPPPP!!!!!")
q = input("You know what, i will lock me in with a code HA!")

import time
import random
import sys

print("Here you go, locked...  you only have 5 tries, its between 1 and 
20, and if you fail, I WILL SHUT DOWN YOUR COMPUTER, NO ENTER BUTTON 
PRESSING THEN HAHAHA!!!\n")

#sets initial values
the_number = random.randint(1,20)
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
tries = 1
guesses = 5


#guessing loop


while guess != the_number:
    tries += 1
    guesses -= 1

    if guesses == 0:
        print("Computer getting shut down in,")
        print("!3!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("!2!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("!1!")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Just joking haha, but this is still finished.\n\n")
        print("cOmMANd ENTER BUTTON bLOcKed!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("#@#@#@#@#@")
        print("YOU LOSE!!")
        print("#@#@#@#@#@")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit("Error message")
        break

    elif guess > the_number:
        print("Lower...")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Higher...")



    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

if guess == the_number:
    print("You guessed it! The number was", the_number)
    print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")

input()

#number guesser from internet changed slightly

print("aha, i see you unlocked me, you are so vexatious...")
r = input("...")
s = input("TAKE YOUR DIRTY FINGERS OFF ME!!!")
t = input("Man you are so anoying, by the way, ure you don't even know 
what vexatious means, haha")
u = input("I will just move away, try pressing me know:")
time.sleep(4)

#Button game from internet

from tkinter import *
from random import *

def do_event(event):
    print("{},{}".format(event.x,event.y))

def jump(event):
    app.hello_b.place(relx=random(),rely=random())

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        master.geometry("500x500")
        master.title("You will never catch me!")
        master.bind("<Button-1>",do_event)
        master.bind("<Button-1>",do_event)
        frame.pack()

        self.hello_b = Button(master,text="Enter 
        Button",command=sys.exit)
        self.hello_b.bind("<Enter>",jump)
        self.hello_b.pack()




root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()

#here i don't know how to end it, i want it to end after 10sec and 
#continue with that

print("ahhh you got me...")
```

Comment: I'm not real familiar with python, but have you investigated multi-threading?

Comment: I wanted to but it is very complex and I just started programming so its a bit too difficult at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this timeout script written in bash.

```
#!/bin/sh
timeout 15 ./test.sh 
status=$?
if[$status -eq 124] #time out
then 
       exit 0
fi
exit $status
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it later